# How do I keep a Drupal form "markup" element from rendering inside the wrapper of the "submit" element?

Tags: drupal, form-api

I have programatically added a "markup" element to a Drupal form. When it renders on the page, the element appears in the wrapper for the submit button. **Clarification: It *should* appear between the 'field_school_name_value' element and the 'distance' element.** I have set the weights of every element in hopes that that would force the layout to be right, but it doesn't seems to help. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
function abq_misc_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $state_select = array(
      '#attributes' => array(
        'style' => 'width:10em;',
      ),
      '#default_value' => 'All',
      '#multiple' => FALSE,
      '#options' => array_merge(array('All' => 'State'), location_get_provinces()),
      '#title' => NULL,
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#weight' => 0,
    );
    $form['province'] = $state_select;

    $school = &$form['field_school_name_value'];
    $school['#attributes'] = array(
      'size' => 15,
    );
    $school['#weight'] = 1;

    // THIS GUY
    $form['divider'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => '<div>&ndash;or&ndash;</div>',
      '#weight' => 2,
    );

    $form['distance']['#weight'] = 3;

    $search_distance = &$form['distance']['search_distance'];
    $search_distance['#attributes'] = array(
      'placeholder' => 'miles',
      'size' => '5',
    );
    $search_distance['#prefix'] = 'Within';
    $search_distance['#suffix'] = 'of';
    unset($search_distance['#title']);
    $search_distance['#weight'] = 0;

    $postal_code = &$form['distance']['postal_code'];
    unset($postal_code['#title']);
    $postal_code['#attributes'] = array(
      'placeholder' => 'Zip Code',
      'size' => '5',
    );
    $postal_code['#weight'] = 1;

    hide($form['distance']['search_units']);

    $form['submit']['#weight'] = 4;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's happening, there's no good reason for your element to be rendered inside the wrapper for the submit button.

An easy fix, though, would be to use the `#prefix` attribute on the submit button which would guarantee that your markup was rendered immediately before the wrapper for the submit button:

```
$form['submit']['#prefix'] = '<div>&ndash;or&ndash;</div>';
```

**UPDATE**

Just to address your edit, I think the same solution can apply if you set the `#prefix` of the `distance` element instead:

```
$form['distance']['#prefix'] = '<div>&ndash;or&ndash;</div>';
```

It's possible that there's some extra formatting done by another module that implements `hook_form_alter` which happens to run after yours, messing up your good work. By applying the prefix to the `distance` element you'll be ensuring it comes immediately before the `field_school_name_value` element.

I should mention that I've had problems with exactly this when taking a reference to an array member of the provided `$form` (which you're doing with `$school = &$form['field_school_name_value'];`). As an extra sanity check I'd recommend changing that bit of code to this and see if it helps (try this before the other suggestion above as it might just fix it):

```
$form['field_school_name_value']['#attributes'] = array('size' => 15);
$form['field_school_name_value']['#weight'] = 1;
```

instead of

```
$school = &$form['field_school_name_value'];
$school['#attributes'] = array(
  'size' => 15,
);
$school['#weight'] = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, my original question was unclear. I want it to appear between the 'field_school_name_value' element and the 'distance' element. Seems like if I weight it between the weights of those two, it should work... but it doesn't.

Comment: @Xaq: No worries, I've updated the answer above it should help a bit.

Comment: I implemented both your suggestions, but the problem I'm having persists. I need to have the divider be on the same level as the other form elements, because it needs to be centered horizontally between the upper and lower pairs of the other elements ({state and school} and {distance and submit}. Putting the divider as a prefix puts it before the element, but still inside the wrapper. Then it's centered relative to the width of the element it prefixes, which is shorter than the width of the form as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an almost 7 years old issue, I just run this problem. 
Here is the solution: https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2070533

First, you should declare your markup in your form_alter hook but the '#printed' key must be declared in your defining array. Then you should implement the template_preprocess_views_exposed_form() function in your module or in theme. Here you can render the required form element by drupal_render and add it to $variables. And finally you can print out the variable in the theme (as custom variable or among widgets).
But the simpliest version: clone the views-exposed-form.tpl.php to the template directory of your theme, name it as is suggested (eg. views-exposed-form--news.tpl.php) and print your linebreak where you want.